# Shell script to find files older than 1st Jan 2010

Tags: linux, shell

I'm looking for a script that find all files older than 1st Jan 2010. The following isn't working for me -

```
date-of-my-file = $(date -r /my-file +%F)
if [ $date-of-my-file -nt "2010-01-01" ]
then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
P.S: touch command is not working on my box with deprecated Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 'find' to search for files created on a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date)

Comment: Do you have `find` and what does "older" mean? Access time, modification time, creation time?

Comment: @khachik - modification time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
find <dir> -not -newermt 2010-01-01
```

This finds all files modified before the specified date.  Do a *man find* and look at the options for *-newerXY* if you want to use something besides modified date.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but `find` arcana is tricky enough to be worth comment. Adding "-type f" will restrict the search to files (ie exclude dirs, symlinks, etc).

Answer (score 1):

you need to use shell commands find with newer option.

it works like: you create a file with timestamp 1.1.2010 and then compare all files with this timestamp

```
touch -t 01010000 /tmp/timestamp<br>
find ~ -newer /tmp/timestamp
```

Comment: Better to be explicit about the year, too, in case someone copies and pastes this in a future year and gets surprising results.

Comment: Am unable to run the "touch" command on my deprecated linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "find" command. There are several flags that allow you to filter file by last modification time, such as -newer, -mmin and -mtime. Do a "man find" for more details.