# Extract file names based on dates [Shell]

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

My test.txt looks like this

```
drwx------+  5 dc staff   170 Jan 19 00:17 stopwords.txt
drwxr-xr-x   4 dc staff   136 Feb 20 21:15 test.pl
-rw-r--r--   1 dc staff   845 Feb 26 00:09 test.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 dc staff   917 Feb 26 00:45 test1.txt
```

I want to Extract those files which are created 1 week before the current date (when the shell script is run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of parsing a text file with a directory contents, you could use `find` directly:

```
find <directory> -ctime +7
```

This will print all the files under `<directory>` that have been created more than 7 days ago.

For more information, please have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/158044/183066).

Comment: Thanks for the link and your answer !!