# In Unix how to list all directories created before a specified date?

Tags: unix

In Unix, how can I list all directories created before a specific date (March 6 2013)?

I do not need to do this recursively.

The present working directory has 70000 folders and I just need to cat out the name of the directories with a create date before 3/16/2013 to text file.

Comment: `man find` is your friend. You can find some inspiration in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date

Comment: This is question for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree that the question would be *better suited* at unix but this kind of question has been asked and been answered on SO since then dawn of the site...

Comment: You can use find command. I think [this][1] may help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date

Comment: I need directories and not files. Pardon my Unix ignorance.

Comment: I came up with this: find  -type d -mtime +43 but only need 1 level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find -type d -mtime +43 -maxdepth 1