# How to view list of backup files on a particular date

Tags: linux, bash, unix, backup

In my office i am taking daily and weekly backups. I am just curious to know if i could view list of backup data on a particular day.

Example: If i have taken backup on 1st august 2013 i.e, on Thursday, i want to view list of backup data on 1st august 2013.

Comment: How about an ls -l and then grep on the time?

Comment: This greatly depends on *how* you are taking backups... by just copying files? by using a backup utility? by using `rsync` or something similar, or `zip`/`rar`/`tar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -newermt 2013-08-02 ! -newermt 2013-08-02
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
ls -l *.bck | grep "Aug  1"
```