# How to copy the limited files by command in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, xargs

When I tried the limited files to another folder, the file format is `.flv`. which is used the command :

```
ls -ltr | grep 'May 16 2013' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs cp -rf /root/directory/.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Debugging step 1: Remove the last pipe and see if the output is what you expect.

Comment: don't parse ls, use find(1);

Comment: All else aside - you do not need to use `grep` if you're already using `awk`: `ls .. | awk '/May 16 2013/{print $9}' | xargs ..`.

Answer (score 2):

As GoodPerson mentioned, the easier way to do this is to use `find` with `exec`.

```
find . -name '*May 16 2013*' -exec cp -rf {} /root/directory \;
```

Observe that, in the command above, the command `cp -rf {} /root/directory` will be executed for every file or directory found by `find`, and where the directory is substituted into `{}`.

*Update*: The command above assumes (probably incorectly) that your filename contains `May 16 2013`. If you actually files that were modified on that date, the problem is a little more complicated and depends on your version of `find`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158095/391161) tells us how to do it with older versions of find.

First, you create two reference files with dates that you specify. Then you find files that live in between those dates. The following three commands will find files on May 16 2014.

```
touch -d '16 May  2014' /tmp/Ref
touch -d '17 May  2014' /tmp/Ref2
find . -maxdepth 1   -newer /tmp/Ref -and -not -newer /tmp/Ref2
```

If you are satisfied with the result of `find`, you can then append the `exec` as I have above.

Comment: not sure the date is in the name of the file :-) Maybe `-ctime` or `-cmin` instead?

Comment: @cadrian, Very good point. I thought he was searching for name with that date.

Comment: @cadrian, I'll put this answer back after I figure out the right syntax for the date flags.