# Find files between 2 dates

Tags: date, unix, datetime, awk, ls

I want to get every files that are between 2 date with this format : YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm

I have some constraints too : i can't write files even in /tmp, and i can't use `find --newermt` because it's an old server.

I tried to use awk without success :

```
ls -l  --time-style=long-iso | awk '{ if (mktime(gensub ("-", " ", $6) " " gensub (":", " ", $7) " 00") >= mktime(gensub ("-", " ", gensub (":", " ", "2014-08-26 12:30")) " 00") && mktime(gensub ("-", " ", $6) " " gensub (":", " ", $7) " 00") <= mktime(gensub ("-", " ", gensub (":", " ", "2014-08-26 12:30")) " 00")) print $8 }'
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You're trying to match filenames that have a yyyy-mm-dd format? or files's mtime/atime/ctime?

Comment: Sorry to forget, it's files mtime/atime/ctime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd see if you can use `stat` with an appropriate format. On my (linux) system, print out the file name and the mtime with

```
stat --format=$'%n\t%y' *
```

Then, to filter based on the mtime:

```
stat --format=$'%n\t%y' * |
awk -F"\t" -v from="2014-08-01 00:00" \
           -v to="2014-09-01 00:00"   'from <= $NF && $NF <= to {NF--; print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that there is an old version of 'find' or that you don't have 'find' at all.

If you do have find, but it's an old version, then there's another way than '-newermt':

[How to use 'find' to search for files created on a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date)

The third answer shows how to create two files with the timestamps you require. Then use:

```
find / -newer /tmp/t1 -and -not -newer /tmp/t2
```

Comment: I have an old version of find. But i can't write files because i have only readings rights. It's a prod server in a big company so i can't make what i want :/