# how to find files on server, which came on specific time period say 1 jan to 31 march

Tags: file, time, find

How to find files on a server, which came on specific time period say 1 Jan to 31 March using grep, without scripts?
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 'find' to search for files created on a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 0):

Can I answer with a command without `grep`?

```
find /path -type f -daystart \
  -mtime -$(( ($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -d '2015-01-01 -1 day')) /60/60/24 )) \
  -mtime +$(( ($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -d '2015-03-31 23:59:59')) /60/60/24 ))
```

This will find any file in the `/path` directory whose modification time is between `2015-01-01 00:00:00` and `2015-03-31 23:59:59` expressed as days ago.

I.e. today is `2015-06-29`, so the command line will be expanded as

```
find /path -type f -daystart -mtime -180 -mtime +89
```

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions such as this one, because it belongs to [su] and is not about programming.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Got it, but it was an interesting problem :)