# bash script for sorting files

Tags: regex, bash

Hi I am new to bash scripting. I am trying to write a code that provides me all the files for the username entered by the user when prompted and the file modified date as entered by the user. I am not able to sort and display the files with the date provided by the user. Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your username: "
read username
echo "Enter the date file is created: "
read date
ls -l | find mypath -user "$username" | find mypath -regextype posix-extended -regex "^[0-9]*[- / .][0-9]*[- / .][0-9]*$" "$date"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through your code one step at a time.

```
ls -l
```

Will print the contents of the directory the script is being run from. You're then sending that output to *find*, which makes running `ls -l` redundant because find doesn't take anything from stdin

You're then sending the output of `find mypath -user "$username"` (which is now just a list of files) to another find command, which again, doesn't take anything from stdin.

Also a quick google of "find created date" returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date) thread, which tells us you can't even use find to get the created date!

Pipes ("|") are used for redirecting the output of one command to be used as the input of another command.

So for modified date, I would use -

```
find mydir -user "$username" -newerat $date ! -newerat $(expr $date + 1)
```

You will have to input the date as yyyymmdd - look in to `sed`, `awk`, and `grep` if you want to expand the functionality (eg. being able to use yyyy-mm-dd).