# display the name of the files from particular date in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, gnu

I wanted to display the list of files from particular date.
Suppose I have 4 files on particular dir..

```
AA (Created on 01-Oct-2015)
BB (Created on 01-Oct-2016)
CC (Created on 01-Oct-2017)
DD (Created on 01-Oct-2017)
```

And if i pass the From date parameter as `01-Nov-2015`
So it should display list of files from that `date like > 01-Nov-2015`
for above parameter it will print

```
BB
CC
DD
```

files only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use, if your `find` supports it (version >= 4.3.3) its `-newerXY` parameter and provide a date.

Example:

```
find /tmp -newermt 01-Oct-2016
```

From the `man` page:

> -newerXY reference
>
> Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is newer than timestamp Y of the file  reference.   The letters X and Y can be any of the following letters:
>
> a   The access time of the file reference
>
> B   The birth time of the file reference
>
> c   The inode status change time of reference
>
> m   The modification time of the file reference
>
> t   reference is interpreted directly as a time

An [official workaround](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html) is to create a file with the proper timestamp:

```
touch -t 02010000 /tmp/stamp
find /usr -newer /tmp/stamp
rm -f /tmp/stamp
```

in your case, use date to get the matching timestamp like this

```
touch -d 10-Oct-2017 /tmp/stamp
find /usr -newer /tmp/stamp
rm -f /tmp/stamp
```

As a side note, you may want to find files more recent than BB using:

```
find -anewer BB
```

Comment: Thanks for  your quick response. It is giving below erro 
find: invalid predicate `-newermt'
I am using GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1) I am using below code to find the files , so is possible to add the Date from parameter  so it will give the files greater than the date from paramter                    
 [CODE] echo "$XX-TOP/AP/in/123"
cd $XX-TOP/AP/in/123/AP/in/000723
find . -type f -print -maxdepth 1 | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'

Comment: I updated my answer with a workaround for `find` older than 4.3.3

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your help. I am using below code to get the number of days. [CODE] today_date=$(date +%d/%m/%Y) mm=$5 dd=$(date -d"$mm" +%d/%m/%Y) echo [[ $(( ($today_date - $dd) / (60 * 60 * 24) ))]]. So I am getting below error " value too great for base (error token is "08")" I am having Todays Date: 16/10/2017 and Date From : 11/08/2017. I tried with adding 10# to the both the dates but still getting same error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use another option in find with more compatibility:

find . -type f -name "something" -mtime +15 ("number of days")

But you have to calculate the number of days between the actual date and the date than you're expecting, dont accept a date only a number.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your help. I am using below code to get the number of days. [CODE] today_date=$(date +%d/%m/%Y)
mm=$5
dd=$(date -d"$mm" +%d/%m/%Y)
echo [[ $(( ($today_date - $dd) / (60 * 60 * 24) ))]]. So I am getting below error " value too great for base (error token is "08")" I am having    
Todays Date: 16/10/2017 and Date From : 11/08/2017. I tried with adding 10# to the both the dates but still getting same error. Thanks in advance