# find files with specific name and specific date command returns wrong result

Tags: linux, centos

I am using centos 7
if I want to find files  that starts with the word image in the directory A

i issue the following command

```
  find  /A -name 'image*'
```

and in order  to write the command that find files that have specific name and issued on specific date and let it be 25/10/2017 for example

Iam issuing the command

```
find -name 'image*' | ls -ali | grep 'Oct 25'
```

but it greps all files in the folder what is wrong in this command

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You command seems wrong, you probably missed the `xargs`:

```
find -name 'image*' | xargs ls -ali | grep 'Oct 25'
```

without xargs, the ouput of find is just thrown away and you take the `ls -ali` of the current directory, which is probably not what you want.

nevertheless find has options to add the date as a search criterion, not sure that's what you really need, but you may have a look

[How to use 'find' to search for files created on a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 1):

You can use find to print the date of last modification:

```
find -name 'image*' -printf "%TD %p\n" | grep "^10/25"
```

or:

```
find -name 'image*' -ls | grep "Oct 25"
```

Comment: i want to move these files to new folder

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask