# Moving files with a specific modification date; "find | xargs ls | grep | -exec" fails w/ "-exec: command not found"

Tags: linux, centos

Iam using centos 7

If I want to find files that have specific name and specific date then moving these files to another folder iam issuing the command

```
find -name 'fsimage*' | xargs ls -ali | grep 'Oct 20' | -exec mv   {}  /hdd/fordelete/  \;
```

with the following error

```
-bash: -exec: command not found xargs: ls: terminated by signal 13
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the -exec as you wrote it is quite meaningless, moreover it seems you are mixing find syntax with shell oe (-exec as you wrote it should be passed to find)

there are probably more concise ways of doing, but this should do what you expect:

```
 find  -name 'fsimage*' -type f  | xargs ls -ali  | grep 'Oct 20' | awk '{ print $NF }' | while read file; do  mv "$file" /hdd/fordelete/  ; done
```

nevertheless, you should take care of not just copy/paste things you do not really understand from the web, you may wreck you system...

Comment: iam new to centos but able to understand this script  thanks alot for your advice

Comment: Parsing `ls` in this way is quite buggy. Any filename with spaces you'll only get the last piece from; filenames with newlines or other nonprintable characters have even less-sensible behavior. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for an in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer already explains, `-exec` is an action for `find`, you can't use it as a shell command. On contrary, `xargs` and `grep` are commands, and you can't use them as `find` actions, just like you can't use pipe `|` inside `find`.

But more importantly, even though you *could* use `ls` and `grep` on `find`'s result just to move files older than some amount of time, you *shouldn't*. Such pipeline is fragile and fails on many corner cases, like symlinks, files with newlines in name, etc.

Instead, use `find`. You'll find it quite powerful.

For example, to `mv` files modified more than 7 days ago, use the [`-mtime` test](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Age-Ranges):

```
find -name 'fsimage*' -mtime +7 -exec mv '{}' /some/dir/ \;
```

To `mv` files [modified on a specific/reference date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158235/404556), e.g. `2017-10-20`, you can use the [`-newerXY` test](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Comparing-Timestamps):

```
find -name 'fsimage*' -newermt 2017-10-20 ! -newermt 2017-10-21 -exec mv '{}' /some/dir/ \;
```

Also, if your `mv` supports the `-t` option (to give target dir first, multiple files after), you can use `{} +` placeholder in `find` for multiple files, reducing the total number of `mv` command invocations (thanks @CharlesDuffy):

```
find -name 'fsimage*' -mtime +7 -exec mv -t /some/dir/ '{}' +
```

Comment: Given as GNU extensions (to `find`) are already in use, you might consider using a GNU extension to `mv`, and making it `-exec mv -t /some-dir {} +` -- that way `find` needs to call far fewer `mv` invocations.