# list command grep current date output filename only

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to know how to list a file by current date and output filename only

my current command:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/test --time-style=+%D  | grep $(date +%D)
```

output:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root test  146 04/03/18 file1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root test  146 04/03/18 file2.txt
```

I tried `ls  /var/www/html/test --time-style=+%D  | grep $(date +%D)`, and it  didn't work.

basically, I want the output as filename only `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

Comment: Do you want to output a list of all files, sorted by date? Or just files with a specific date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -l /var/www/html/test --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D) | awk '{print $7}'
```

edit: formatting code

Answer (score 0):

I believe `find` command is better for the task.
Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date).

```
find /var/www/html/test -type f -newermt $(date +%F)
```

I think it is more elegant solution.